# Tying to decode JSON without object path

Tags: json, swift, decode

I am a complete newby to Swift and have a JSON file that im looking to decode, bit its just an array of objects (strings directing to other JSON Paths) with no object definition:

Example of list.json:

```
[
"filepath1.json",
"filepath2.json",
"filepath3.json",
"filepath4.json",
"filepath5.json",
"filepath6.json",
"filepath7.json",
"filepath8.json",
"filepath9.json"
]
```

when trying to decode i am getting an error:

**typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))**

For the purpose of the example i have removed the web url (supplierURL) where the file is stored
example decoding that I'm using:

```
    let supplierURL = "list.json"

    func getSuppliers()  {
        let urlString = supplierURL
        performRequest(urlString: urlString)
    }

    func performRequest(urlString: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
            let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)
            let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                if let safeData = data {
                    self.parseJSON(supplierList: safeData)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }

    func parseJSON(supplierList: Data){
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        do {
            let decodedData = try decoder.decode([SupplierList].self, from: supplierList)
            print(decodedData)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

I have also tried:

```
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Array<SupplierList>.self, from: supplierList)
```

and

```
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(SupplierList[0].self, from: supplierList)
```

with no luck.
any assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
let list = try decoder.decode([String].self, from: supplierList)
```

You didn't show SupplierList, but you should be able to construct it from that array.